# Failed to execute msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql, sql-server, sp-send-dbmail, dbmail

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
> Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.

My code is:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [StagingMX].[dbo].[_CVA] 
           WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, [Completion time], GETDATE()) = 1 
             AND [A] = 'IQQ' AND [B] = 'MDD')
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
              @profile_name = 'Admin', 
              @recipients = 'something@gmail.com',
              @body = 'Good Morning,',
              @query = 'SELECT * FROM [StagingMX].[dbo].[_CVA] WHERE DATEDIFF(day, [Completion time], GETDATE()) = 1 and [A] = IQQ AND [B] = MDD;',
              @subject = 'Customer Voice';
END
```

The problem has to be something in relation with how I'm trying to implement the query in regards to the email context (what's inside the query works fine if I run it by itself outside of the email). I've been successful in sending other emails and implementing other queries.

For example, if I modify the email query to this one it works perfectly:

```
@query = 'SELECT TOP(1) * FROM [StagingMX].[dbo].[_CVA] ORDER  BY [ID] DESC;',
```

I've already done:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON sp_send_dbmail TO PUBLIC
```

Comment: *"I've already done: "grant execute on sp_send_dbmail to public"."* That isn't what allows you to email. YOu should be giving the appropriate `USER`s, in `msdb`, the `ROLE` `DatabaseMailUserRole`. I *strongly* suggest against giving `public` membership of that role.

Comment: @Larnu could you please show me in code how to do this ? I'm new to the sql language and perhaps I could fail in the syntaxis if I miss something.

Comment: `ALTER ROLE DatabaseMailUserRole ADD MEMBER <User Name>;`

Comment: @Larnu I did it manually via: Databases > System Databases > msdb > Security > Users > Properties > Membership. And before the code I even wrote: (USE msdb EXECUTE AS USER = 'myusername') but it keeps giving me:                                                                                                                                  Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259. 

Do you think it has something to do with this or perhaps something else ?

Comment: Aside... `SELECT *` is really lazy. You should always specify the exact columns you need.

Comment: If you copy the exact query out of your `@query` parameter and try to execute it in a new SSMS tab does it execute without error? I expect not. Are `IQQ` and `MDD` actually columns in your table, or are they meant to be string literals `'IQQ'` and `'MDD'`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I've ran the code in another tab and it works, yes. Also, IQQ and MDD are columns from my table. I've done most of what others say in threads regarding this topic but unfortunately nothing seems to work :/